# XML root node with slash... unexplained?

Tags: xml, root

Why would you have a rootnode in an XML document that looks like this:

```
<return/>
```

Why is that slash there?  I have never seen an XML document like this, however in an application I am debugging, a root node looking like this one is created, and appending any child nodes seems to be failing.

Removing the slash crashes the program.

It uses MSXML DOM in C++ under windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<foo/>` is equivalent to `<foo></foo>`. This is known as an [*empty element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-eetag). Without the ending `/`, the open tag will not have a corresponding closing tag, and thus an error.

Answer (score 1):

That is the root node of the xml document and it has no child elements. That's why it has no ending tag.

Comment: Actually it does have a closing tag. This notation is said to be `self closing`, so the closing tag is implied, but it is there.